# Is there a single word for set of people playing against each other?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the set of players playing individually in a card game. The word 'team' doesn't sound good as it implies that they should help each other. I considered 'gang', 'bunch', 'circle' etc. But none seems to fit.

Background:
I'm designing a card game and want to introduce a 'team' concept where a moderator can establish a --- of a set of players. This ---- can engage in a game interactively at suitably planned time slots.

Edit : Thanks all for the answers/comments. So, it looks like that there is no obvious/common word that I missed. I think I will go with the term 'circle' or 'gang'.

Comment: *Partners* (or *partnership*), perhaps?

Comment: It's not really clear what the status of the "set of players" is, but perhaps the neutral *group* will do.

Comment: In poker, this is termed *the table*.

Comment: In the card game of Bridge, it's partner. However, there are only four players in Bridge.

Comment: Maybe a "crew", "faction", or "contingent"?

Comment: The term "players" would be fine; "participants" would also be O.K. The term "circle" is often used to describe a group of people who are playing cards together.

Comment: 'Pool' might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***cohort*** works.

businessdictionary.com:

> **[cohort](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/cohort.html)**
>   Group whose members share a significant experience at a certain period
>   of time or have one or more similar characteristics .

ODO:

> **[cohort](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/cohort#cohort)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **2** [treated as singular or plural] A group of people banded together or treated as a group.
>   ‘a cohort of civil servants
>   patiently drafting legislation’

Answer (score 1):

How about players or competitors?

Player 
Noun
A person taking part in a sport or game

Competitors
Noun
A person or group of people who take(s) part in a sporting contest.